# How to deploy a particular folder from a github repo to netlify instead of the whole repository?

Tags: github, netlify

I want to deploy a application which is existing in a folder in a repository to netlify (using import from github feature.). Again I don't want to deploy the whole repository, I just want that particular folder. there are also other folders in the same repo. The catch is all of them are in the same branch. Is it possible to deploy that way?
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/johst.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this as follows

1. Import the repository into Netlify where your project folder is located
2. *While deploying your project in ***'Basic Build Settings'***, you can set your project folder as the base directory*

From the image shared in the question, I concluded that you want to deploy '*advice-generator-app-main*'. In this case, you can set '*advice-generator-app-main*' as your base directory as shown in the image below.

[image: View this image]